# Check if the first number after my username is greater than 500

Tags: regex

I am trying to check if the first number after my username is greater than 500. The structure of an XML file I am trying to search is as follows:

```xml
<username>Joker876</username>
<text xml:space="preserve" number="524">
```

I came up with a script that filters numbers correctly, but if the number is less than 500, it searches for the next one. I would like to do so that if the number is not matching the pattern, it doesn't search for a number that matches, but instead, for my username. Example:

```xml
<username>Joker876</username>
<text xml:space="preserve" number="524">     <-- this should match
<username>Username here</username>
<text xml:space="preserve" number="524">     <-- this should not match
<username>Joker876</username>
<text xml:space="preserve" number="50">      <-- this should not match and should not match the number 
<username>Joker876</username>                    two lines below
<text xml:space="preserve" number="524">
```

Here is my code:

```regex
<username>Joker876</username>.*?number="([5-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})"
```

Also, I will be using this regex code in the Notepad++ find feature.

Comment: Why don't you simply replace your `.*?number="` with `\r\n<text xml:space="preserve" number="`? Or you could only allow one opening Tag after your </username> like `...</username>\r\n<[^<]*number="...`.

Comment: You are right, I could use literal text rather than `.*?`. And, I am going to try you suggestion out.

Comment: Or, `<username>Joker876</username>\R<[^<>]*number="([5-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})">`. Note it will match also numbers that are equal to `500` (you said *greater than*).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
<username>Joker876</username>\R<[^<>]*number="([5-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})">
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8s6pu2/1)

**Details**

- `<username>Joker876</username>` - literal text
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- `<` - a `<` char
- `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
- `number="` - a literal text
- `([5-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})` - `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` or `9` followed with any two digits or a non-zero digit followed with any three or more digits
- `">`  - a literal text